# Can't complete First Post review when reaching the daily vote limit

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, voting-limits

When reviewing First Posts (but probably Late Answers as well), if you use your last (up/down)vote for the day, you can't complete the review. See the GIF below, after clicking the 'I'm Done' button the review counter stays on 1,146.

[image: screencast]

Just to be sure, I know that *after* this review I'm not able to review First Posts anymore, and that is fine. However, I should be able to complete this review.

This issue is similar to [Downvoting an answer during review puts user below minimum reputation requirement for reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295064/295232) and would be solved if some of the checks whether you're able to review (required reputation and if you haven't reached the daily voting limit) are moved to the *beginning* of the review rather than upon completion. Some other checks (number of reviews per day) should probably be kept at the end.

Comment: Aren't FP/LA simply greyed out when daily vote limit is reached? (it happened to me once, I thought it was because of this; though the queues are proabbly still accessible through IDs, I guess)

Comment: Yes, they are, but I'm talking about a situation where I'm in the queue just before I reach the limit. I.e. my vote is still registered, but I can't complete the review.

Comment: Is the review registered on your review summary list? And what is the review result (Skip, Reviewed, ...) stated there?

Comment: I haven't checked, but I think it's not visible in my review history at all before completing the review.

Comment: The same bug [also occurs for delete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339240/my-last-delete-vote-of-the-day-used-in-low-quality-posts-queue-always-triggers-a) in the Low Quality Posts queue: using your last delete vote on a post as a trusted user will invalidate the review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a check that runs when you submit a review which verifies that you're even allowed to review things in that queue - this check rules out a lot of weird / bad stuff, like folks reviewing after being banned from review, after being suspended, without having earned the privilege of reviewing, etc. It's also the check that grays out the queue on the top-level /review directory when you visit it.

One of the checks here for most queues is: do you have enough votes left to *do* anything in this queue?

- First Posts / Late Answers: gotta have up/down votes left.
- Close: gotta have close votes left
- Reopen: gotta have reopen votes left

The fix here is to ignore just that last check *if* there's a specific task being reviewed *and* you've already voted on the associated post.

Very similar (but not quite identical): [My last Delete vote of the day used in Low Quality Posts queue always triggers an error and invalidates the review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339240/my-last-delete-vote-of-the-day-used-in-low-quality-posts-queue-always-triggers-a/341940#341940)

This'll be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Mind responding to the similar issue mentioned in the question?

Comment: So... That one is *not* fixed, because it's much, much more of an edge-case than this and... Frankly it's slightly more of a headache to fix in a way that makes sense.