# My last Delete vote of the day used in Low Quality Posts queue always triggers an error and invalidates the review

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete

I've experienced this almost daily on Stack Overflow, and now I believe I've recently figured out the pattern of this bug.

Requirements:

- over [10,000 reputation](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) if the low quality post is a question (it almost *never* happens)
- over [20,000 reputation](/help/privileges/trusted-user) in general, in order to have access to delete votes for answers.
- not a ♦ user, because you need a finite amount of votes for this issue.

Steps:

Visit [the low quality queue](/review/low-quality-posts) and when you cast your **LAST ["Delete"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZOet.png) vote** of the day (**not** the "Recommend Deletion" vote), then an error occurs:

> [An error occurred when reviewing this item. Please try again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ0AY.png)

Refreshing the page demonstrates that the review got invalidated:

> [This item is not reviewable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaj0z.png)

For reference, the review item was: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24697740. As I'm not a moderator, I do not know if the original flag became "helpful", "disputed" or something else.

It may be possible that it actually happens for the **LAST+1** Delete vote (I didn't count precisely), but in any case it seems like some off-by-one error somewhere: if it's the last+1 vote, then the review queue should be considering it as "Recommend Deletion" instead of invalidating the review.

Please accept my apologies for not recognizing the bug earlier: I believe I've accidentally invalidated many reviews like that in the past months because I can do 20 reviews a day, but I have less than 20 delete votes a day, and as such potentially triggering the issue daily.

Comment: Similar (but different) bug: [Can't complete First Post review when reaching the daily vote limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320321/295232)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause here is a sanity-check which attempts to verify that a given review action is actually valid for that review: for a LQ answer, that means a Delete action is only valid if you have delete privileges, the answer scores <=0, and you still have delete votes remaining for the day; a RecommendDelete action is only valid if one or more of the above are *not* true.

Here's where it went wrong: when the review task is shown, you have one vote left, Delete is a valid action, so the Delete option is shown; by the time this is checked, you've used your last vote, and Delete is invalid.

The fix here is to treat Delete as a valid action *when you've already voted to delete the answer*, even if you're out of votes.

Related (but subtly different): [Can't complete First Post review when reaching the daily vote limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320321/cant-complete-first-post-review-when-reaching-the-daily-vote-limit/341941#341941)

This will be fixed after the next build.